# background positioning of svg for different devices

Tags: html, css, svg, background, position

There are two circles in the background, one at top-left and one at bottom-right.
For desktop it's ok but for mobile, it is supposed to be as is in the design.
I can't understand how to solve this issue. Can u pls help with this?

Given design:

[image: actual design]

What I made:

[image: What I made]

background circles are not in the right position

Github - [github](https://github.com/SAHIL-NAZIR/profile-card-component)

```css
body {
  background: url('images/bg-pattern-top.svg'), url('images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg'), #19a2ae;
  background-position: -80% 50%, 170% -40%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 70%, 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you should use is viewport width (`vw`) and viewport height (`vh`) for dimensions and position of your circles.

When width > height (large screens like desktop), you should use `vw`, and when height > width (smaller and vertical screens like mobile), you should use `vh`. Obviously you'll have a larger number of breakpoints than 2, but this example could help you:

https://codepen.io/tpmarc/pen/PojGbwx